# ListView isn't being updated

Tags: c++, qt

What/how shall I force view to update itself? My listView is not being updated and only after if I press show/hide button (which shows/hides this view) on my dialog the view is being updated.

```
void No_Files_Match_Regex_Dialog::show_files(bool show)
{
    current_selection_model_->clear();
    if (show) {
        current_selection_model_->set_entries(*(caller_->current_selection()));
        listView->setModel(current_selection_model_);
        listView->setVisible(show);
        showFilesBtn->setText("Hide Files");
    } else {
        listView->setVisible(false);
        showFilesBtn->setText("Show Files");
    }
}

#include <QtDebug>
void No_Files_Match_Regex_Dialog::another_selection()
{
    this->hide();
    current_selection_model_->clear();
    //caller_->current_selection().clear();
    //qDebug() << "Last action: " << caller_->last_add_action_;
    caller_->last_add_action_->trigger();
    auto tmp = caller_->current_selection();
    if (tmp) {
        current_selection_model_->set_entries(*tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you are using?

Comment: Can you show the code of `set_entries` ?

Comment: I'd wager that, in set_entries, you're not calling beginResetModel() and endResetModel().

Comment: @JediLlama no I do not call it. I call beginInsertRows and endInsertRows

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
QApplication::processEvents();
```

to handle events which are waiting in the event queue (e.g. repaint events).

If this command on its own is not sufficient, you can do

```
listView->update();
```

or

```
listView->viewport()->update;
```

instead or before calling `processEvents()`

Comment: it doesn't seem to have any effect ;*(